# Car pulls to the right when braking - started after putting jack stand under control arm

Tags: suspension, wheels, alignment, braking, 328i

So when I jacked my car through a front central jack point, I managed to raise the car high enough to put the jack stand under the designated jack point on the left side of the car but it wasn't high enough for the right side one. As such I put the jack stand under the control arm  of the right side wheel.

[image: Position of the jack stand on the control arm shown by a red circle on attached picture]

The above picture is not from my car and it is used to illustrate the position of the jack stand on the control arm (red circle), ignore the arrows. As a right hand drive car, the stand was put on the driver's side wheel (opposite wheel tho the one pictured). From the placement of the jack stand, it looks like the link between the control arm and the subframe of the car took the most stress, the control arm itself looks quite sturdy.

From then on, I need to keep the steering at about 10 degrees offset to the right for the car to drive straight. Occasionally, the steering wheel gives a feel that it wants to steer clockwise when the car is about to come to a stop while braking. Rarely, under certain conditions, the steering sharply steer clockwise up to 30 to 40 degrees offset to the right. This event only happens on a specific place of my usual route, when the car is under braking and about to come to a stop under a slight right hand turn. Also the car feels lighter to steer clockwise than steer counterclockwise. The steering seem to have some slack between 5 and 10 degrees. However, if I align the steering for it to go straight, it will go straight if I release the steering wheel. As well, the car doesn't veer during a high speed braking whatever the braking input.

From the above description, what could the issue be? a bent control arm? A shot ball joint? Worn bearings? And can this compensated by a wheel alignment?

Edit: Clarification regarding the confusion between the description and the picture.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the make/year/model/engine of the vehicle? You're in Australia, correct? So this should be a right hand drive car? This looks to be the left side of the vehicle (passenger side for you)?

Comment: Yes, I'm in Australia, the car is a 2012 BMW 328i, the picture is not from my car and is just for illustration purpose on where I put the jack stand on the control arm. The jack stand was put on the wheel on the driver's side.

Comment: Jacking on control arms can bend them - and even a small amount is enough...

Comment: What work did you do once you had jacked the vehicle up?

Comment: It was to change the engine oil.